# I thought Object was a unknown typed object? Not in XmlSerializationWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, webservice-client

I have a webservice that always returns a ReturnObject that is a class I have written like this:

```
public class ReturnObject
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Object Data { get; set; }
}
```

When I return a single object like an int or string etc in Data it is OK but when I want to return a list of typed objects the client that running the webservice as a WebReference getting this exception:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document
>    ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Typen
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Transticket.Domain.Models.ApsisMailingList,
>   Transticket.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] kan inte användas i den här kontexten.    vid
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String
>   name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)    vid
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String
>   n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)    vid
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write3_ReturnObject(String
>   n, String ns, ReturnObject o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>   vid
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write6_GetListsResponse(Object[]
>   p)    vid
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer5.Serialize(Object
>   objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)    vid
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    --- Slut på stackspårning för interna undantag ---
>   vid System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter
>   xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String
>   encodingStyle, String id)    vid
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues, Stream outputStream)    vid
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues)    vid
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()    --- Slut
>   på stackspårning för interna undantag ---

This exception is not in the webservice, it's in the client call to the webservice after returning the data.

If I do another ReturnObject there and I specify a list of typed objects as data, it works well.

Someone have an idea how I generalize this? I have always thought that List is a type of Object but looks like a .NET bug, or I have missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` does not include type information in the output (contrast with `BinaryFormatter`); as such, there is no robust way of deserializing `object`, as the xml could be (quite literally) anything.

The same is true of most contract-based serializers (`DataContractSerializer`, protobuf-net, etc).

Basically: don't do that. `object` is not a useful thing to use on a  web-service, and that cannot work.